# History.pushState not working on android chrome browser but works on desktop and tablet

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

For some reason, the urls change correctly on desktop, but doesnt work on android or iphone browsers. When I click on the buttons, they just send me to the current post.

```
<script>

  function updateNavigationButtons(data) {

    var entries = data.feed.entry;

    var currentUrl = window.location.href;

    var currentIndex = -1;

    // Find the index of the current post

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

      if (entries[i].link[4].href === currentUrl) {

        currentIndex = i;

        break;

      }

    }

    var previousUrl = '';

    var nextUrl = '';

    // Set the previous and next URLs based on the current index

    if (currentIndex > 0) {

      previousUrl = entries[currentIndex - 1].link[4].href;

    }

    if (currentIndex < entries.length - 1) {

      nextUrl = entries[currentIndex + 1].link[4].href;

    }

    var previousButtonTop = document.getElementById('previous-button-top');

    var nextButtonTop = document.getElementById('next-button-top');

    var previousButtonBottom = document.getElementById('previous-button-bottom');

    var nextButtonBottom = document.getElementById('next-button-bottom');

    if (previousUrl !== '') {

      previousButtonTop.addEventListener('click', function() {

        history.pushState(null, null, previousUrl);

        updat<script>

  function updateNavigationButtons(data) {

    var entries = data.feed.entry;

    var currentUrl = window.location.href;

    var currentIndex = -1;

    // Find the index of the current post

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

      if (entries[i].link[4].href === currentUrl) {

        currentIndex = i;

        break;

      }

    }

    var previousUrl = '';

    var nextUrl = '';

    // Set the previous and next URLs based on the current index

    if (currentIndex > 0) {

      previousUrl = entries[currentIndex - 1].link[4].href;

    }

    if (currentIndex < entries.length - 1) {

      nextUrl = entries[currentIndex + 1].link[4].href;

    }

    var previousButtonTop = document.getElementById('previous-button-top');

    var nextButtonTop = document.getElementById('next-button-top');

    var previousButtonBottom = document.getElementById('previous-button-bottom');

    var nextButtonBottom = document.getElementById('next-button-bottom');

    if (previousUrl !== '') {

      previousButtonTop.addEventListener('click', function() {

        history.pushState(null, null, previousUrl);

        updateButtons();

      });

     eButtons();

      });

      previousButtonBottom.addEventListener('click', function() {

        history.pushState(null, null, previousUrl);

        updateButtons();

      });

      previousButtonTop.style.display = 'inline-block';

      previousButtonBottom.style.display = 'inline-block';

    } else {

      previousButtonTop.style.display = 'none';

      previousButtonBottom.style.display = 'none';

    }

    if (nextUrl !== '') {

      nextButtonTop.addEventListener('click', function() {

        history.pushState(null, null, nextUrl);

        updateButtons();

      });

      nextButtonBottom.addEventListener('click', function() {

        history.pushState(null, null, nextUrl);

        updateButtons();

      });

      nextButtonTop.style.display = 'inline-block';

      nextButtonBottom.style.display = 'inline-block';

    } else {

      nextButtonTop.style.display = 'none';

      nextButtonBottom.style.display = 'none';

    }

  }

  function updateButtons() {

    fetch('/feeds/posts/default/-/' + encodeURIComponent('Dark Elf and the Villainess Daughter') + '?alt=json&max-results=999')

      .then(function(response) {

        return response.json();

      })

      .then(function(data) {

        updateNavigationButtons(data);

      });

  }

  // Update navigation buttons when the script is loaded

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    updateButtons();

  });

  // Update navigation buttons when the window is resized

  window.addEventListener('resize', updateButtons);

  // Update navigation buttons when the history state changes (e.g., back/forward button)

  window.addEventListener('popstate', updateButtons);

</script>
```

I was expecting the previous and next buttons to be changed according the previous and next posts of the same category, but that didn't work on mobile. It worked on desktop, however.